# confusing messages about `type` from xmllint when trying RELAX NG pattern facet

Tags: types, pattern-matching, relaxng

I'm still learning RELAX NG, and some input requires me to check the data content with a pattern.
After searching the web I tried this (fragment, modeled after the example in [The Simplest Possible Pattern Facets](https://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-9-SECT-2.html)):

```relax-ng
  <define name="DT.Test">
    <a:documentation>Data Type: test</a:documentation>
    <data type="string">
      <param name="pattern">"[0-9]+"</param>
    </data>
  </define>
```

However when running `xmllint` using that, I got an error message saying:

> element data: Relax-NG parser error : Type library 'http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0' does not allow type parameters

So I removed the `type` parameter and tried again with this definition:

```relax-ng
  <define name="DT.Test">
    <a:documentation>Data Type: test</a:documentation>
    <data>
      <param name="pattern">"[0-9]+"</param>
    </data>
  </define>
```

Astonishingly the message was:

> element data: Relax-NG parser error : data has no type

So it seems `xmllint` is unhappy with both: Specifying a `type`attribute, and not specifying one.
I'm confused.

## Appendix

### Version of `xmllint`

```text
> xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20904
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma
```

Answer (score 0):

Still I don't quite understand the messages, but adding a `datatypeLibrary` attribute to the `data` element makes `xmllint` happy:

```xml
  <define name="DT.Test">
    <a:documentation>Data Type: Test</a:documentation>
    <data datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
          type="string">
      <param name="pattern">"[0-9]+"</param>
    </data>
  </define>
```